# place a textview in an interface with android

Tags: android, xml

I try to make this copyright band in my interface:

[image]

this is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contentDescription="News "
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/Transparent"
        android:gravity="fill" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarsplash"
            android:indeterminate           =   "true"
            android:layout_width            =   "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height           =   "wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop        =   "5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom     =   "5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft  =   "true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable   =   "@layout/customprogressbar"/>

        <com.ofss.fcdb.mobile.android.tablet.ui.components.FCImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/oraclelogosplash" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<!--     this is my textview for copyright -->
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#fcfcfc"  
        android:paddingBottom="50dp">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/securelogin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />


           <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/K_COPYRIGHT"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I work with an android Tablet,this is what I get:

[image]

the textview is displayed in the bottom of the page or I want it like the first page,and with my code the text doesn't appear :(
I am an amateur in android 
any help please
thanks for help

Update:

thanks Mohit Trivedi for your answer,this what I get as a result:

[image]

is it possible to put the image in the center like the text,it doesn't work with

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contentDescription="News "
    android:scaleType="fitXY">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/Transparent"
        android:gravity="fill">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarsplash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@layout/customprogressbar" />

        <com.ofss.fcdb.mobile.android.tablet.ui.components.FCImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/oraclelogosplash" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--     this is my textview for copyright -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#fcfcfc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/securelogin" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/securelogin"
            android:text="@string/K_COPYRIGHT"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Replace your layout with above code it will work

Comment: @user3821206 your welcome please accept answer if you are satisfy

Comment: I have an other question Sir how can I put the security icon in the center,I get  it in the left part of the copyright band and the text in the center

Comment: But if you put security answer in center then what about text isen't it overlapping?

Comment: Sir I just want to put the icon+the text in the center if it is possible because I have tried with android:layout_gravity="center" and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This is the minor issue of orientation/gravity issue of the bottom part of the layout. Just change the center_vertical to center that will give exact result as you want